# EFCore 6.0.1 creates an additional row with null values for deeply nested object arrays in the entity model on Create/Update

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have encountered a very strange behaviour for simple Create and Update operations.

The project has some deeply nested EF models whereby when a `_entity.Add(model)` is called all of the values are expected to be created/updated for all the related joined tables.

When `_entity.Add(model)` or `_entity.Update(model)` is called, for objects which are a 1-to-many (represented as a List in the model) and additional row is created out of nothing with null values but valid identifier.

For example, SQL profiler shows the following (for params @p62 to @p76)

```sql
DECLARE @inserted4 TABLE ([Id] uniqueidentifier, [_Position] [int]);
MERGE [Parties] USING (
VALUES (@p32, @p33, @p34, @p35, @p36, @p37, @p38, @p39, @p40, @p41, @p42, @p43, @p44, @p45, @p46, 0),
(@p47, @p48, @p49, @p50, @p51, @p52, @p53, @p54, @p55, @p56, @p57, @p58, @p59, @p60, @p61, 1),
(@p62, @p63, @p64, @p65, @p66, @p67, @p68, @p69, @p70, @p71, @p72, @p73, @p74, @p75, @p76, 2)) AS i 

....

....@p59=NULL,@p60=NULL,@p61=NULL,@p62='BF510D23-58B9-4702-BB99-08DA18B25663',@p63=NULL,@p64=NULL,@p65=NULL,@p66=NULL,
@p67='System',@p68='2022-04-07 16:19:10.057',@p69=NULL,@p70=NULL,@p71=NULL,@p72=NULL,@p73=N'',@p74=NULL,@p75=NULL,
@p76=NULL,@p77='04C2E963-7A4E-47F4-A6FB-69AA2B5F2A64',....
```

I have not encountered this behaviours before, inspecting the models before `.SaveAsync()` is called does not reveal anything such as an additional row being added to any of the object's lists.

Looking at the EF config for one of the tables with this behaviour does not reveal anything either

```cs
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PostalAddress> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("PostalAddresses");
            builder.HasKey(e => e.Id).IsClustered(true);

            builder.Property(e => e.CreatedBy)
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("('System')");

            builder.Property(e => e.CreatedDate)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getutcdate())");

            builder.Property(e => e.HouseNumber).HasMaxLength(128);

            builder.Property(e => e.LastModifiedBy)
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("('System')");

            builder.Property(e => e.LastModifiedDate)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getutcdate())");
        }
```

Comment: Why do you call `_entity.Update(model)`? EF Core automatically detects changes.

Comment: *The project has some deeply nested EF models* - but what does the entity graph look like? Does your Person have a nearly empty Address object attached to it, for example? Does your class look like `class Person { Address WorkAddress {get;set;} = new()}` ? The new is a problem; it will create empty objects.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add a value to the foriegn key of the nested table or delete the property of the whole table in the table related for example product has category as a navigation prop and also has categoryId if you donot supply a value to categoryId it will add new category with null all values although u set not null but it will take the value from category prop name abd id so remove it and supply a value to the id

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Please edit it to make it a bit more readable, as it's now one long sentence with no stops, which is a bit confusing.

Comment: i mean when we have two tables with relations like a category and products ,a category contains many products so you put  a navigation property of a category and a navgation id also to it. when you donot supply a value to category id it will insert a full category with null values suppling that new id to the product without suppling the needed id that u donot supply it so make sure to supply that value